# Slack desktop sometimes very sluggish and slow

Tags: ubuntu, slack-desktop

I am using Slack for Linux (Beta) 4.16 on Ubuntu 20.04 and experience very slow and sluggish typing sometimes (not always, hard to reproduce). I have 40GB of RAM and quite a powerful laptop, and it happens even when my CPU is barely working and I still have like 80% of RAM free.

Disabling the spell checker as some have suggested doesn't help. Does anybody else have this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try to disable the hardware acceleration:

File -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Other options -> Disable hardware acceleration

That should help.

Comment: I have the same issue on popos 22.04 with version 4.25.0. The above didn't fix it for me.